# Changing the color of a script that doesn't contain a color code

Tags: html, colors

I'm not great with html, but people I have asked are telling me it is impossible to change the color. The script comes from a separate website and is not my own. I would like to change the color of the link. All my other links are black, and I would like to keep them that way, but I want this one to be #f2f2f2. Although there isn't a color code in the script itself, is there a code I can add elsewhere to change it?

The script won't show up so I have screenshotted it and here is the link to see

```
<script src="http://tc.freehostedscripts.net/tcounter.php?url=kittycocaine.tumblr.com&name=x" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This script is from an outside website, and is used to track activity. The website that created the script will not allow me to change anything in the script posted above.

I have total control over where I can place the script, but I would like it to show up in top left so I was just going to post it at the top of the head tags. I put the entirety of my html into pastebin in case that helps with anything

http://pastebin.com/PbuYkDbQ

Comment: I think you accidentally didn't include your script.

Comment: @user2532739 He forgot to press `Ctrl + K`. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question, this script is adding some url link to the page.

Is there any reason you can't style it with CSS for whatever color you want? If the inserted href doesn't include any class, you could target it to be inserted into a div with some class in it (or just re-purpose whatever element its nested in, if there are no other urls).

Your question is still unclear, but possibly what you could try is:

1. Surround your script with a named div, e.g. `<div id="activityLink"> { your script code ... } </div>`
2. Add a style section to the head of the html: `<style> </style>`
3. Create a CSS rule for the link color within the style block : `#activityLink a { color: #f2f2f2; }`

Links can have different colors depending on their state, see [CSS Links](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp) page on W3schools.

If you want to do any web development, I'd strongly suggest learning CSS, a basic knowledge is quite easy to learn and very useful.

Answer (score 0):

I see your file has the extension `.php` it has to be `.js`.

According to your comment, *"I'm not even sure how to do that I'm sorry, what would I do?"*, As you said that is a file from another domain. If that domain is yours please change the file extension from `.php` to `.js` by going into your folder and right click edit it and then remove that `.php` and then write `.js` in there.

One easy way could be to search for [CSS](https://www.google.com.pk/search?q=CSS&oq=CSS&aqs=chrome.0.69i64j69i59l3j69i62l2.2272j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#sclient=psy-ab&q=learn%20CSS&oq=learn%20CSS&gs_l=serp.3..0i7i30l4.3390.6528.0.7221.12.11.1.0.0.8.1031.6250.4-3j5j1j1.10.0....0.0..1c.1.20.psy-ab.zJpNvtWtCHY&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.49784469,d.bGE,pv.xjs.s.en_US.MpiVkF51mpA.O&fp=b8e520bb2a69db4&biw=1280&bih=709) thing on google.

Comment: @AlyS I am saying to change your file extension from `.php` to `.js`.

Comment: I'm not even sure how to do that I'm sorry, what would I do?

Comment: Just literally substitute .js where it says php?

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui Its possible that is a PHP script that emits valid JS for inclusion in other sites.

Comment: @Alok but then he is using `.php` in the `<script>` tag. IDK if that matters so I posted about CSS :)

Comment: The script isn't mine it's from a different website, and the website says that if the script itself is messed with it will no longer work

Comment: I got the script from freehostedscripts.net and it is used to track activity on the blog. The website I got it from says not to mess directly with the code I posted earlier because it won't be able to track what I want

Comment: How it's related to colours?

Comment: I have all links set to show up as black, but I want this script to show up as a different color than the rest

Comment: please make your own script or use CSS>